# How to use mercurial "diff-patterns"?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Mercurial (or maybe just TortoiseHG) seems to support a `[diff-patterns]` configuration option (for hgrc) but atypically for Mercurial I can't locate any documentation on this feature.

I would have expected to find it perhaps here: https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html, but no mention.

It is briefly [mentioned here](https://tortoisehg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common.html) (or [here](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/tortoisehg/latest/tortoisehg.pdf) in PDF) stating only:

> In order to support file extension based tool selection, TortoiseHg
>   has added support for a [diff-patterns] section equivalent to
>   Mercurial’s merge-patterns section.

No real explanation. I have found a scant few example by Googling, but still nothing comprehensive about how it is to be used.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have not heard of [diff-patterns]. A quick scan of the hg code also did not find anything. I did find in the thg code (as expected).

There is documentation at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration that includes discussion of merge-patterns. Sounds like they are similar if not nearly the same.

Sounds like it might help identify what diff tool to use for file extension patterns in the same way merge-patterns helps identify the merge tool to use for different file.extensions.